# Obtain value from a table; one index is in a range

Tags: excel, range, lookup-tables

I have 2 user input values. One represents `number of users`, the other represents `license term`.

While `license term` is fixed, e.g., `12 months`, `24 months`, or `36 months`, `number of users` is in a range. E.g., `1 to 99 users`, `100 to 199 users`, `200 to 500 users`.

I have an excel table that represents `prices` based on these values. It is setup as follows:

```
C1     C2     C3     C4     C5

FROM   TO     12M    24M    36M   
1      99     $10    $8     $6
100    199    $9     $7     $4
200    500    $5     $4     $3
```

Given 2 inputs such as `123` users and `24` months, I need a formula that can return the price in the table (in this case, `$7`.

Appreciate the help!
Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the inputs?  Post what you have written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$E$4,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$4,"<"&G2+1),MATCH(H2,$C$1:$E$1,0))
```

Assumptions:
1. Price table is in range A1:E4
2. Input number of user on column G, and term on column H (12M, 24M, 36M)
3. Put the above formula on column I which is for prices.

Comment: Interesting use of `COUNTIF`. I would have used `MATCH` with a `1` for the final argument. +1

Comment: Thanks both Clint and L42 for your suggestions. Both worked flawlessly but L42's also worked when (e.g.) I used numbers for the Term or text (e.g., 12, 24, 36 or "12m", "24m", "36m") giving me a bit more flexibility. DIdn't ask for that originally I know...but have to choose one. – Tony 5 secs ago edit

Comment: glad to be of help :) @Doug Glancy haha it just happen that the values are numbers. but match would have done the trick as well

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement a VLOOKUP for this

I took your data and made a quick Excel Sheet

The formula I used was:

```
=VLOOKUP(J4,A2:E4,INT(J3/12)+2,TRUE)
```

Where J4 is the Value for the number of users (123)
      J3 is the number of months (24)
      A2:E4 contain the sample table ( Headers in A1:E1)

The idea here is because your terms are evenly spaced, you can translate them into an index for the column to use (j3/12)+2

Then you set VLOOKUP to use an approximate match for your user range

Please let me know how it goes! Thanks